# Noconflict using 2 JS versions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding a script into my magento site and am getting protoype errors since this script uses a different version of JS

I tried to do

$.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.

with no sucsess

What would the best way to do a no conflict be?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        event: "click hoverintent"
    });
});

var cfg = ($.hoverintent = {
    sensitivity: 7,
    interval: 100
});

$.event.special.hoverintent = {
    setup: function() {
        $( this ).bind( "mouseover", jQuery.event.special.hoverintent.handler );
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $( this ).unbind( "mouseover", jQuery.event.special.hoverintent.handler );
    },
    handler: function( event ) {
        var that = this,
            args = arguments,
            target = $( event.target ),
            cX, cY, pX, pY;

        function track( event ) {
            cX = event.pageX;
            cY = event.pageY;
        };
        pX = event.pageX;
        pY = event.pageY;
        function clear() {
            target
                .unbind( "mousemove", track )
                .unbind( "mouseout", arguments.callee );
            clearTimeout( timeout );
        }
        function handler() {
            if ( ( Math.abs( pX - cX ) + Math.abs( pY - cY ) ) < cfg.sensitivity ) {
                clear();
                event.type = "hoverintent";
                // prevent accessing the original event since the new event
                // is fired asynchronously and the old event is no longer
                // usable (#6028)
                event.originalEvent = {};
                jQuery.event.handle.apply( that, args );
            } else {
                pX = cX;
                pY = cY;
                timeout = setTimeout( handler, cfg.interval );
            }
        }
        var timeout = setTimeout( handler, cfg.interval );
        target.mousemove( track ).mouseout( clear );
        return true;
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: It uses a different version of Javascript...?

Comment: Your question is not complete enough for us to help. Are you using Prototype as well jQuery?
What are the errors?

Comment: Yes i use magento which is on protoype.

Once I add the above code into my page it breakse the zoom and gives "is not a function" errors 

http://www.threejnyc.com/new/index.php/shop/pajamas/lucy/lucy-greendots.html

is a link to the error page

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using jQuery in this anonymous function you can wrap everything in the anonymous function:

```
(function ($) {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        event: "click hoverintent"
    });


var cfg = ($.hoverintent = {
    sensitivity: 7,
    interval: 100
});

$.event.special.hoverintent = {
    setup: function() {
        $( this ).bind( "mouseover", jQuery.event.special.hoverintent.handler );
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $( this ).unbind( "mouseover", jQuery.event.special.hoverintent.handler );
    },
    handler: function( event ) {
        var that = this,
            args = arguments,
            target = $( event.target ),
            cX, cY, pX, pY;

        function track( event ) {
            cX = event.pageX;
            cY = event.pageY;
        };
        pX = event.pageX;
        pY = event.pageY;
        function clear() {
            target
                .unbind( "mousemove", track )
                .unbind( "mouseout", arguments.callee );
            clearTimeout( timeout );
        }
        function handler() {
            if ( ( Math.abs( pX - cX ) + Math.abs( pY - cY ) ) < cfg.sensitivity ) {
                clear();
                event.type = "hoverintent";
                // prevent accessing the original event since the new event
                // is fired asynchronously and the old event is no longer
                // usable (#6028)
                event.originalEvent = {};
                jQuery.event.handle.apply( that, args );
            } else {
                pX = cX;
                pY = cY;
                timeout = setTimeout( handler, cfg.interval );
            }
        }
        var timeout = setTimeout( handler, cfg.interval );
        target.mousemove( track ).mouseout( clear );
        return true;
    }
};


}(jQuery));
```

Basically you're wrapping the entire anonymous function around your javascript, passing jQuery into the anonymous function as $ and it will "override" prototype just within THIS anonymous function.

Is that helpful?

Comment: No luck on fixing the zoom
But if i remove the above code it works good.

Do i have a conflict with this script or the zoom?

The page is http://www.threejnyc.com/new/index.php/shop/pajamas/lucy/lucy-greendots.html

Comment: Have you gone through your console log? You've got a lot of js files 404ing, which is causing uncaught TypeError's.

To get to console in Chrome, click View » Developer » Javascript Console

Comment: I see those 404's but dont believe that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: There are a few image 404's but i see these when i add the code for the accorian menu i pasted above 
is not a function